# Launch application as root user in GNOME

Tags: centos, gnome, sudo

I've got CentOS 6 installed on my server. A few users want to have access to it via VNC, so I installed GNOME separately. Everything works okay, but I want to have possibility to run applications as the root user without providing the root password (just like `sudo` in the terminal). Where can I set this up in GNOME?

I know that if I would install GNOME during the CentOS installation, I could just `visudo` and add certain users and that would be it. But when I installed GNOME separately it can't be done like this.

Comment: You *can* use visudo!

Answer (score 2):

There's a program called `gksudo` which asks user for this user's own password, not root password. Don't forget to add this user to sudoers or wheel group.

Comment: unfortunately there is no `gksudo` or similar available in CentOS 6